# How do I mount an already unencrypted bitlocker drive?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ntfs

So, I'm currently running Ubuntu in a VM, and my drive is already unencrypted with Bitlocker. Strangely, one of the partitions is the one I booted from, but that's with a Linux filesystem. The other partition is NTFS. So under the disks utility the partition is labeled HPFS/NTFS, but under Gparted it is labeled Bitlocker. There is no ID when checked with blkid.

Have checked everywhere and all the answers assume starting with an encrypted drive.

Can Ubuntu mount this NTFS "Bitlocker" filesystem?

Edit:

I'm running Windows 10 and VMware Workstation 12.

Comment: Are you currently running Ubuntu from a VM in a Windows host?

Comment: That's right. Under the disks utility the contents are unknown as well.

Comment: How to access the host partitions depends on the virtualization software. In Virtualbox it's usually with shared folders in each VM settings. VMWare seems to have more sophisticated options. Please edit your question and post all that info. Generally speaking the OS running in the VM can only see what the software allows and no, bitlocker isn't relevant if the *shared* drive is unencrypted in the host OS.

Comment: What really matters is 1. what you intend to achieve and 2. the information requested above that you should edit into the question, namely Windows host, the VM software you're using and 3. what have you done so far to achieve whatever goal you have.

Comment: Ok, OP has been edited. Really, I just want to be able to mount the other partition on the drive. Before it was encrypted I would usually just right-click either in disks or Gparted or even nautilus and mount the partition. Now, however, I'm not able to do so and haven't found a way yet. I've even installed dislocker and tried to mount the partition with my private key, but no go.

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html

Comment: Yeah... that didn't work.

Comment: Here's what happened -  https://postimg.org/image/qcmb5bsa1/
https://postimg.org/image/qq5wxknal/
https://postimg.org/image/qan0rb6vh/
https://postimg.org/image/5cx8vqk6f/
https://postimg.org/image/ybt1zwlsf/

Comment: Now when I boot up it boots into emergency mode.

Comment: It's not detecting sda1, which is the NTFS bitlocker encrypted drive. When I try to repair the packages, it fails to start creating volitile files and directories, and failed to start LSB: Apparmor initiation.

Comment: Is it screwed...? Luckily I have a semi-recent image of the drive.

Comment: Whew, I fixed it kind of. I just removed the NTFS partition from fstab and now it boots into Gnome.  So basically I'm back at step 1, I can't mount the NTFS partition. When I try to mount it in terminal it says it can't find it in fstab.